# How to use fetch command in jGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

This is my code for add remote.

```
  FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
            Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(gitdir)
                    .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
                    .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
                    .build();
            Git git = new Git(repository);

            StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
            config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", url);
            config.save();
```

Now how to use fetch command using jGit?

Comment: You should prefer the `AddRemoteCommand` to add a remote reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JGit [`FetchCommand`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.7.0.201704051617-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/FetchCommand.html):

```
git.fetch().setRemote("origin").call();
```

Comment: I am getting this error "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin"

Comment: Hey @MilindaKasun, sorry I don't JGit in my job anymore. Is it possible that your origin is not added to Git/JGit repository correctly? or it is added but its value is invalid? A valid remote should look like `https://github.com/mincong-h/mincong-h.github.io.git`, you can find it on any GitHub project by clicking the "code" button.